# How to fetch or give query to get another table column to my table through in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

How to fetch or give query to get another table column to my table through in spring boot.

I am doing some spring project and I have created two table here.

```
----------------------
|    Table 1        |
----------------------
 |  UserID          |
 |  InstrumenName   |
 |  Qty             |
 |  Price           |
 |  Date            |
----------------------


----------------------
|    Table 2        |
----------------------
 |  InstrumenName   |
 |  LTP             |
 |  Sector          |
----------------------
```

so while saving I am saving the Table data.

Here is my code for controller class.

```
@PostMapping("/employee")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
```

Here I am following all the rules like JPA repo, Model and COntroller.

Now when I wanted to get this data I wanted to add LTP from table 2 with respect to instrument name.

I am very new here so what I suppose to do. I have get code as well in my controller but I wanted to add LTP as well?

Do i need to write sql procedure or any businees login java code.

This would be my sql query :

```
SELECT table1.UserID, table1.Qty,table1.InstrumenName, table1.Price,table2.LTP             
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.InstrumenName=table2.InstrumenName;
```

ANy help will be helpfull.

Comment: I don't understand your question. what did you try so far? How would yo do that with SQL?

Comment: IN Sql I would have used join. My query would be like this which i have updated in question. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Perfect and what result do you like? Do you already have a class?

Comment: I want to have `(UserID, Qty, InstrumenName, Price, LTP)` this value in my result. I have model, controller and JPA repositry for table 1 and table 2. where by using post and get my data is getting updated. As I have written there in my question. 

Do I need to create extra class ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a class/interface to hold the result.

If it's read only you can use an interface if you also want to receive data then use a DTO (if using Java 16 a Record would be a great fit)

Please read the documentation about projections.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: thanks,  I am able to achive now the data with my required json. @Simon

Comment: Great! If my answer was helpful please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I have still some issue. I m not understanding. Can u please check this again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212371/joing-two-tables-in-jpa-repository
I have explian bbit more in question